# --allow-running-insecure-content (Chrome 38+ Issue)

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

I have an iFrame in an HTTPS application. That iFrame is calling an HTTP page to display. So due to mixed content Chrome does not display data hence displays the shield button. Did some search on Internet and they said to add a flag to chrome shortcut menu.

flag: --allow-running-insecure-content

But even after adding the flag in shortcut menu's Target still i could not able to view the insecure content automatically. Still it displays the Shield icon and i have to select the "Load insecure script" to display the data.

Am using chrome 38. Is the above flag removed from Chrome 38??? Or is there any other ways to display insecure content automatically in chrome???

Comment: I have the same issue since last week. Hope someone knows...

Comment: I solved it by checking task manager and killing residual chrome.exe processes: http://superuser.com/questions/634448/google-chrome-switch-allow-running-insecure-content-doesnt-work-anymore?rq=1